# RADIUS is ignoring request to authentication address.freeradius-server in docker

Tags: freeradius, radius

I use the following mirror.[enter link description here](https://hub.docker.com/r/freeradius/freeradius-server/)
I execute the following command.

> radtest bob test 127.0.0.1 0 testing123

Output for

```
 Sent Access-Request Id 69 from 0.0.0.0:59466 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
    User-Name = "bob"
    User-Password = "test"
    NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.0.2
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "test"

   Sent Access-Request Id 69 from 0.0.0.0:59466 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
    User-Name = "bob"
    User-Password = "test"
    NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.0.2
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "test"
   
   Sent Access-Request Id 69 from 0.0.0.0:59466 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
    User-Name = "bob"
    User-Password = "test"
    NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.0.2
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "test"
   
   (0) No reply from server for ID 69 socket 3
```

The user entry in **etc/raddb/clients.conf**

```
client dockernet { 
      ipaddr = 172.17.0.0/16        
      secret = testing123}
```

The entry in **/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize**:

```
bob    Cleartext-Password := "test"
```

Output of

```
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 127.0.0.1 port 59466 proto udp
Ready to process requests
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 127.0.0.1 port 59466 proto udp
Ready to process requests
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 127.0.0.1 port 59466 proto udp
Ready to process requests
```

Can anyone help me?What did i do wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: in your docker file you can add ENV RAD_CLIENTS=172.17.0.0/24 towhitelistthe ip's